# Jquery Ajax's success function not called

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am calling a MVC controller method from Jquery ajax.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Customer/GetDetails",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                    alert(value);
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

I am having an entity called **Customer**.

Controller Method fetches record from DB and stored as List of Customer and am returning that list in JsonResult type.

```
public JsonResult GetDetails()
{
    CustomerDAL customer = new CustomerDAL();
    IList<Customer> custList = customer.GetDetail();
    return Json(custList);
}
```

But my ajax's success function is not at all called here.

Comment: add this: `dataType:'json',`

Comment: waht is browser error message. Debug it and get the what is error?

Comment: `cache:false` works only GET and HEAD request. Check [HERE](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for all ajax parameter properties.

Comment: Am not getting any messages

Comment: Are you sure? Use firebug and debug it, get the request message.

Comment: have you place a breakpoint inside the controller method and see if the actionresult is called in the first place? also as @AliRiza said use firebug or chrome tools see if there are any errors

Comment: Controller method is getting called and am getting the result in the List. In Ajax function I cant get the returned result. While debugging using chrome debugger am not getting any errors. It just coming out of the ajax function.

Answer (score 5):

You don't have to specify the `content-type` because it set the type in which the server is expecting the data, you are not sending any so no need to set it explicitly, secondly set the `dataType` to `json` which is the format in which the client is expecting data from the server. But I really doubt that it could be the cause of any error.

Add an error callback to make sure something went wrong on the way back like

try

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Customer/GetDetails",
            dataType:'json',
            async: false,//WHY??
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                 alert("success");                
            },
            error:function(){
              alert("something went wrong");
            }
        });
```

Use

1. Firebug or chrome tools to examine the ajax request and set what is the status code returned.
2. Place a breakpoint inside the Controller to see if the `ActionResult` is hit when the call is made.

EDIT

mark your JsonResult with the `HttpPost` annotation like

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetDetails()
        {
            CustomerDAL customer = new CustomerDAL();
            IList<Customer> custList = customer.GetDetail();
            return Json(custList);
        }
```

Comment: I tried your sample. Its hitting the error. typeof(console) is undefined here.

Comment: please try again i have edited the answer ... and see if the alert in error callback comes up... if you are getting type of console is undefined here then probably the success handler is being called because in the error function i have checked for the undefined console

Comment: Sorry.. typeof(console) is not "undefined" here. Getting the message OOOps

Comment: Status code returned is 500. Error thrown is "Internal Server error"

Comment: Adding [HttpPost] annotation too not solving the problem

Comment: the error code says it all, something is going wring at the server end

Comment: @dakit with some server technologies you do have to specify the format or the server will fallback to  a default and break some requests ... this happens in asp.net web api requests all the time for me. Also, sometimes its perfectly valid to make a synchronous request, I have code that needs data from the server in the middle of some of my js functions.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your line

```
 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
```

with this one

```
contentType: "application/json",
```

and add datatype

```
datatype: 'json'
```

Comment: you should use async to true. that will make server wait

Comment: @Syeda you are right making `async:false` kills the purpose of ajax, but still that is not the cause of the problem

Comment: Make sure 2 more things. add debug to GetDetails is it realy going there and put an alert after success before calling each is it poping alert or not?

Comment: GetDetails() is getting called. That is sure. In Ajax method, it just skips the ajax function and coming out of the function.

Answer (score 1):

Got into that today. The problem, that the "success" event wasn't fired was, that there actually wasn't a "success" from the jQuery perspective: the json code returned by the server was malformed!
So: double check your json format, i.e. with JSON Lint at http://zaach.github.com/jsonlint/ or something else.
The ajax function is very "tolerant" against any false/erroneous settings, but malformed json code is definitively an error. As long as the error event gets triggered, there IS an error.

Answer (score 0):

You have an object list as List in ajax-success function.

to parse it try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Customer/GetDetails", // or better way '@Url.Action("GetDetails", "Customer")'
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (index, customer) {
                alert(customer.id, customer.name, customer.surname);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

controller

```
public JsonResult GetDetails()
{
    CustomerDAL customer = new CustomerDAL();
    IList<Customer> custList = customer.GetDetail();

    return Json(custList);
}
```

for example assume that your CustomerDAL model

```
class CustomerDAL
{ 
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string surname { get; set; }
}
```

Modify alert message for your CustomerDAL model. I dont know what properties in your model.

Answer (score -1):

Your code:

```
return Json(custList);
```

Change it to:

```
return Json(new SelectList(custList));
```